# MVC dataannotations decimal datatype validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, decimal, data-annotations

My application is made on ASP.NET MVC4.And i am using MVC dataannotations validations in my viewmodel classes.

I have one decimal type column.And i am using below regular expression to validate it.

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$",ErrorMessage = "Amount is invalid.")]
 public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

And with the help of above regular expression its working well.
But I want to add one more condition there.Which is if someone enters number like:

```
12.
445.
```

Then it should accept it and also should adds .00 means (12.00,445.00) automatically.

FYI, I have changed the above regular expression like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9]|.)?$",ErrorMessage = "Amount is invalid.")]
```

And by this its accepting the numbers like:

```
12.
445.
```

But due to MVC datatype decimal filed its giving the another validation message..

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how i can manage that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd offer using shadow field:

```
class myModel
{
    ... 
     public decimal Amount { get; private set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$",ErrorMessage = "Amount is invalid.")]
    public string AmountStringed  //use this field on your form input
    {
        get { return Amount.ToString(); }
        set { Amount = decimal.parse(value); } //assign Amount
    } 
}
```

So you don't have to do any hacks with either client or server side valiedations